# Angularjs route on button click is not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I have been trying to make a angularjs application where I want to route to a different html page on a button click. But is not working for some unknown reasons.

My html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
     <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular-route.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

<body ng-controller="Controller">
<h1>Plunkr Example</h1>
  <button ng-click="changeview()">ClickMe</button>
  <h1>MainPage</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

My Code

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute'])

app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
}]);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/Details', {
            templateUrl: 'details.html'
        }).
        when('/Main', {
             templateUrl: 'main.html'
         }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/Main'
        });
  }]);

app.controller("Controller", function($scope,$routeParams,$location){
  //$scope.ProductId = $routeParams.id;
  $scope.changeview = function () {
        console.log('in function changeview');
        $location.path('/Details');
    }
})
```

Here is my [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/W8mf6ltUaXmPwltpRh6N?p=preview)

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have ng-view directive in index.html

```
 <div class="viewWrapper">
        <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/oeEHmTdyFYkCxwcMYR1r?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked like charm. Dont know how I missed that part.

Comment: Just one more doubt. Now the url I can see "http://localhost:3000/#/Main" and "http://localhost:3000/#/Details" on click. Is it possible to remove hash from URL ? I would prefer to have url like "http://localhost:3000/Main" and "http://localhost:3000/Details" . Please suggest something.

Comment: @sand [Here is a link for how to make your URL's pretty](https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag)

Comment: I tried , $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);  as per the url you suggested but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You have missed to add the ng-view directive. It needs to be included for the routing to be able to rendered the templates

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

Working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UE5OLnmasUvGZsU0lZL9?p=preview)